# Can I ask questions about software that is intended to be used online?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, websites

Can I ask questions about software that is intended to be used online? An example could be online virus scanning software.

In the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq), does it only refer to software that users install?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *online*. My desktop email program is also intended to be used only. It's not a whole lot of fun without a network connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web applications are off-topic:

> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - **websites or web services** like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

Comment: @wizlog, [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be the appropriate Stack Exchange site.